# Loop creating non-clickable buttons

Tags: javascript

I have an issue with my buttons. I'm generating new buttons in a grid in javascript and only those rows that have 4 buttons (full rows) have clickable buttons. Why are the buttons disabled in incomplete rows?

```
results.innerHTML = '<div class="row">'
                    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                            results.innerHTML +=
                                '<div class="col-md-3">'
                                    + button
                                +'</div>'
                    rowCount++;
                    if(rowCount % 4 == 0) {
                            results.innerHTML += 
                                '</div><div class="row">'
                    }
            }
            results.innerHTML +='</div>'
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: And readable, for that matter.

Comment: what is `button`?

Comment: Where's the code for the 'button' variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why are the buttons disabled in incomplete rows?

This line

```
results.innerHTML = '<div class="row">'
```

Doesn't just create the **start tag** of the `div` inside `results`, it **will also try to implicitly close the tag at the same time**.

You need to use `innerHTML +=`  once at the end. (assuming `button` is a **valid markup** itself)

```
  var html = "";
  html += '<div class="row">';
  for (i = 0; i < size; i++) 
  {
       html +='<div class="col-md-3">' + button +'</div>';
       rowCount++;
       if(rowCount % 4 == 0) 
       {
           html += '</div><div class="row">';
       }
  }
  html +='</div>';
  results.innerHTML += html;
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of that behaviour. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What does your click handler look like? Are you grabbing the buttons by class? If so you'll need to create a specific class name for the buttons. I find it easier to do this with jQuery, because you can use `$(this)` inside the click handler to refer to the exact button that was clicked even while multiple buttons have the same class name.

If you are using jQuery: `$(document).on('click', '.className', function(){ //do stuff});` is necessary for grabbing elements created after the document has already loaded.

I believe there is also a purely Vanilla JS way to do it, maybe someone else can provide that solution.

Cheers!

Comment: The issue is resolved. The villain was innerHTML. Your post is good advise for later implements though, thanks